# ReactJS: получение JSON из Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

Всем привет.

У меня есть компонент App:

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        data: {
            id: null,
            created: null
        },
        clicked: false,
        loading: true
    };

    render() {
        const data = this.state.data.id === null ? null : <Data data={this.state.data}/>;
        const title = this.state.clicked ? <TitleDone/> : <Title/>;

        return (
            <div>
                {title}
                <div className="main">
                    <button
                        className=" btn btn-outline-secondary"
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.setState(() => {
                                return {
                                    data: api.getResource(),
                                    clicked: true
                                };
                            });
                        }}>
                        Нажать
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="main">
                    {data}
                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

По нажатию кнопки в компоненте Api идёт запрос на бэкенд, который возвращает JSON с двумя полями: `id`, `created`.

Собственно, запрос:

```
getResource = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`${this._apiPath}${this._logUrl}`);

    if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Could not fetch ${this._logUrl}` +
            `, received ${res.status}`)
    }
    return await res.json();
};
```

res.json() выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Network.Response выглядит так:

```
{"id":87,"created":"2019-04-18 17:26:28.948"}
```

То есть, данные JSON обёрнуты в Promise.
В компонент App данные приходят как `undefined`, то есть, после выполнения запроса данные `state` выглядят так:

```
data: {
    id: undefined,
    created: undefined
}
```

В этом виде это всё улетает в компонент Data.
Подскажите, как мне правильно извлечь данные и передать их в компонент App, чтобы проинициализировать поля полученными значениями id и created.

Comment: А если так попробовать `data: await api.getResource()`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в таком случае, теперь не проверяет state.data.id на null и не выводит <Data/>

Comment: А если еще добавить `onClick={async () =>....`?

Comment: Проверьте что возвращает функция `api.getResource()` и подумайте, можно ли её использовать внутри `setState`

Comment: Вам нужно сначала дождаться результата выполнения запроса, а уже потом вызывать setState

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю переписать код рендеринга компонента (метод `getResource` возвращает `Promise`, отсюда и `undefined` лежит в данных):

```
onClick={() => {
  api.getResource()
    .then(jsonData => {
      this.setState({
        data: jsonData,
        clicked: true
      });
    });    
});
```

Навесим на метод `getResource` один `then`, внутри которого вызовем метод `setState`. Есть небольшой совет, не рекомендуется использовать стрелочные функции в рендеринге. [Использование стрелочной функции при рендеринге](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render) создает новую функцию каждый раз при рендеринге компонента, что может влиять на производительность.

Также, как было написано в комментарии - не очень хорошо давать модели знания о структуре состояния. Поэтому переносить вызов `setState` внутрь метода `getResource` было бы не очень хорошо. Можно передавать колбэк, или навешивать `then` на промис и внутри уже менять стейт. Так, метод получения данных не будет знать о структуре состояния.

Comment: Добавлять модели явное знание о структуре состояния вида? Это что, рубрика вредных советов?

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, совет вредный. Согласен. С колбэком возможно будет не такой уж и плохой совет.

Comment: А не лучше ли использовать then или await, чтобы не смешивать стили?

Comment: Что значит "добавлять тормоза"? Там что, есть какая-то принципиальная разница в производительности?

Comment: *"или имеется в виду навесить then на метод getResource"* - ну конечно же, `api.getResource().then(callback)`

Comment: Кто именно будет "висеть" и где? Почему-то при вызове getResource никто не "зависает", хотя там внутри await тоже используется.

Comment: Так, теперь последний вопрос. Нафига вы советуете переписать getResource, да ещё и обзываете это промисификацией? Если что, вторая часть вашего ответа прекрасно будет работать и с авторским getResource!

Comment: Промисификация, потому что работа с функцией, которая возвращает промис. Видимо это понятие в этом контексте тут не совсем уместно, так как это больше подошло бы, если бы промисов не было, а мы их сюда затянули. Переписал изначально, а потом в конечном варианте не убрал, согласен, смысла нет переписывать `getResource`.